# How can I perform a where query on a collection of strings in OData without using ToList?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have several IList values that are stored as dash-separated strings in the database, not my preference, that's just how they were stored.

So as an example I get one of those back in a model like this:

```
    [Column("Appliances")]
    private string appliancesString { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public override IList<string> Appliances { get {
            return this.appliancesString.TrimEnd('-').Split('-');
        }
        set {
            appliancesString = String.Join("-", value) + "-";
        }
    }
```

Then inside of the context that gets the table on the database that contains this I use this inside of the OnModelCreating override:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
             base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
             modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => {
                 var properties = c.ClrType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.Name == "appliancesString");
                 foreach (var p in properties) {
                     c.Property(p).HasColumnName("Appliances");
                 }
            });
        }
```

Any filter call to my API that doesn't reference that or any of the other ILists works perfectly.   The issue comes in when I try to make a call on any of them.   Such as in this case with something like:

```
 $filter=Appliances/any(s: s eq '01')
```

That of course returns:

```
 The specified type member 'Appliances' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

If I turn my IQueryable into a List, it will work on smaller tables, but I can't do ToList() as I have over 90k rows in the table, the class has 390 variables, this is querying so that takes forever and didn't return a result even after waiting several minutes.

What can I do to get this to query against the value and not fail without using ToList?   Any help or even pointing in the direction where I might find some help would be appreciated.

Strangely enough, as I haven't had any responses to this I decided to try converting it to an Enum and going that way.  Since I thought perhaps the issue was just that the collection or IList of strings, though I've tried it as an ICollection, IEnumerable, and IQueryable, couldn't tie out to something wiwh an Id.   Using an Enum called Appliance and having an IList Appliances instead, I still get the LINQ to Entities error.

Hopefully this might provide some more info to let someone help me with this issue.

Comment: In that case you'd want to do something like `.Any(x => x.applianceString.Contains("-01-"))` and avoid the parsing that can only be done in memory and not translated to SQL.

Comment: @juharr That would probably work, but how would I go about implementing that in OData?   The query is handled by OData, through its Queryoptions, not me.

Comment: I don't have any experience with OData, so I'm not sure how you'd translate it to work.